# Why does using a variable in settings.ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS won't let me use {% ssi %}?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

### Problem

I'm using Django 1.3. I will have to use many different JavaScript functions (like 10 or something) in my template.

What I first did was to put them in the `<script>` tag, which worked fine. But now that it works, I want to separate them from the template code. It would make the code way more read'able.

So I thought of using the `{% ssi "..." parsed %}` thing. Since I use Django template tags in my JavaScript code, I can't just link them from my static files with `<script src="..."></script>`.

Here is what works :

```
# This will allow the {% ssi %} tag to include files from the given paths
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS = (
    '/THIS/IS/THE/FULL/PATH/TO/MY/PROJECT/static/js/',
)
```

Here is what does not work :

```
# Project root for further paths
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# This will allow the {% ssi %} tag to include files from the given paths
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS = (
    PROJECT_PATH+'/static/js/',
)
```

I double-checked that the two strings were the same (with `./manage shell`) and they are exactly the same (with trailing `/` and all).

---

### Questions

- Why does the second code renders me `[Didn't have permission to include file]` in my template ?
- Also, how should I link the file to include in the `{% ssi %}` tag ? Since `{% get_static_prefix %}` does not work, I'm currently using the file's full path, which is ugly.

Comment: Based on what you have said above, I don't believe you. I think that there is something that is breaking besides the code you have posted, and as you have said, the strings are the same. Can you make a small Django project that is the smallest size you can that still exhibits this problem? A [Short, Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/), so to speak.

Comment: Re'did it, unfortunately I experience the same issue. I put the the paths (with `PROJECT_PATH` and w/o) in `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` and then printed it. The both strings were the same, I don't get how any background code could break this though. Is is possible that Django disable the use of variables in such a sensitive tool ?

Comment: Found a module which could help me to do what I want ([django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor)). Without the `{% ssi %}` tag, it allows the use of template tags in the compressed files. I'll come back here and answer my own question if it worked, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As odd as it may appear, I didn't make any change in my `settings.py` but it is now functionnal. I believe Mike Cooper was right and some remote code was breaking `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` path.

Answer (score -2):

`ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` is likely a constant due to it's naming convention. Constants aren't meant to be variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(programming)#Naming_conventions

Comment: This isn't a matter of constants and variables; there are no such thing as constants in Python, only variables that are not intended to change.

Comment: Making a path *constant* with a prefix which is common to the whole project doesn't mean it is going to be changed everyday but every day the project structure is going to change (production could be an example).